# CocoaPods fail for Flutter Gallery

Tags: flutter, dart, cocoapods

I am trying to start [Flutter Gallery](https://github.com/flutter/gallery) with `flutter run -d macos`. It fails:

```
...
Error: To set up CocoaPods for ARM macOS, run:
  arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi

Exception: Error running pod install
```

Running `arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi` does not help. Running `flutter clean` does not help too.

What can be missing?

I have Apple M1 Pro chip in my laptop. Can it be the reason?

- My flutter version: 2.13.0-0.0.pre.776
- The full console output is [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tgx5ovf6rkD6LHg6w76FqYQCJmGDVU9oX0LQbEHNSbg/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if `pod install` solves your problem, but installing ffi is not enough. You must also run the `pod` commands using `arch`.

For example.

```sh
arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
```

Comment: Here is what I got after running it in project directory: '[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.'

Comment: You need to run it in the `ios` directory of your app.

Comment: It seems it pushed things forward. Now I am getting the error "ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcodebuild", not a developer tool or in PATH
  Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun xcodebuild -list -project Runner.xcodeproj". It seems I need to install xcode.

Comment: If you want to build for iOS, this is necessary. You can run `flutter doctor` which should help you getting started and setting up everything necessary.

Comment: @TimBrückner, you're a lifesaver :)) Cheers !